# Can software be patented after being made public?

Tags: patentability, law, grace-period

Let's say I made software initially publicly available, but some time in the future I decided I wish to patent it. Could I? Is there any time limit on how long after making software publicly available that I have to patent it?

Comment: Is this for the US or another country?  Also in the US software alone is not patentable based on 35 USC 101

Comment: @Plepleus The US

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the United States, for any invention you have 1 year to file:

> 35 U.S.C. 102   Conditions for patentability; novelty and loss of right to patent.
>   A person shall be entitled to a patent unless —
>
> (b) the invention was patented or described in a printed publication in this or a foreign country or in public use or on sale in this country, more than one year prior to the date of the application for patent in the United States

Comment: Most other countries give no grace period. I.e., the patent must be filed before making the product publicly available.

Comment: And some countries give 12 months grace period and some gives 6 months.

Answer (score 8):

Note that as of March 2013 (for apps filed after then) these rules change in the US; there is still a one-year grace-period -- but only as to *your own* disclosures.  If someone else publishes the concept (or something that would make your invention obvious) before you file then you are (probably) out of luck.

Comment: Do you have a reference/source?